# React: Not getting the correct data in the inner map on click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const handleMenuItem = (e, name, addr) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(addr);
}

{Object.values(addressList.address).length &&
      addressList.address.map((a) => (
        <Grid item sm={4} key={a.addrId}>
          <Card>
            {showCheckIcon[a.addrId] ? (
              <IconButton className="my-address-checked">
                <CheckCircleIcon />
              </IconButton>
            ) : (
              <React.Fragment>
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="more"
                  aria-controls="long-menu"
                  aria-haspopup="true"
                  onClick={handleClick}
                  className="my-address-verticon"
                >
                  <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  id="long-menu"
                  anchorEl={anchorEl}
                  keepMounted
                  open={open}
                  onClose={handleClose}
                >
                  {options.map((option) => {
                    console.log(a);
                    return (
                      <MenuItem
                        key={option.name}
                        onClick={(e) => handleMenuItem(e, option.name, a)}
                      >
                        {option.icon}
                        {option.name}
                      </MenuItem>
                    );
                  })}
                </Menu>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}

            <StepLabel className="text-left">
              <h4>{a.addrCustName}</h4>
              <p>{a.addrAddress}</p>
              <p>{`${a.addrCity}, ${a.addrPincode}`}</p>
              <p>{`${a.addrState}, ${a.addrCountry}`}</p>
              <p>{a.addrCustPhone}</p>
            </StepLabel>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      ))}
```

I noticed when my `handleMenuItem` handler is called, it is getting the incorrect data. I believe it is getting the last data as the loop is finished by the time. Basically, what `handleMenuItem` does is, it selects the address for delivery based on the click event, however, it is selecting the next address when the click event is fired. What is that i could do to make it work as expected ?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a running codesandbox? The code I see doesn't to be able to match what you describe. Can you explain better what "getting the last data as the loop is finished.." and "... selecting the next address..." mean? There is only one address `a` for all iterations of the inner mapping loop over the `options`.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-solomon-23ri1?file=/src/App.js. Kindly have a look @DrewReese

Comment: You will notice, if you click on first address verticon and delivery address, It would select the next address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

When a user clicks on the More-Menu `IconButton`, the onClick handler assigns the current target to `anchorEl`. There is only one of these, so when mapping the `address` the `Menu` `anchorEl` prop of all mapped elements is set to the same target, i.e. the last one wins out.

## Partial Solution

I say this is a partial solution as it only addresses the exhibited behavior of "selecting the last element" of the address array. You'll need to massage the `anchorEl` references to get the popup to locate correctly.

- Add a selected id state value

  ```
  const [selectedAddrId, setSelectedAddrId] = useState(null);
  ```
- Remove `const open = Boolean(anchorEl)`
- Test the `open` condition if the current address' `addrId` matches

  ```
  <Menu
    id="long-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    keepMounted
    open={a.addrId === selectedAddrId}
    onClose={handleClose}
  >
  ```

[image: Edit nervous-pond-9bpsy]